# Spring 3 MVC - form:errors not showing the errors

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-annotations

I am using annotation based validation but for one of the forms I am not able to show any errors using the `form:errors` tag. When I debug the method, I can see the `BindingResult` has errors, but for some reason its not being displayed on the form. I am stumped as I have got it working on other forms, but for some reason this particular form is having issues. Any pointers are greatly appreciated.

Here is some code from the controller, I have the copyCartForm as a @SessionAttribute as well in the Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(params="action=Confirm Copy", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String copyCart(@Valid CopyCart copyCartForm, BindingResult result) {
    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        logger.debug("errors in form" + result.toString());
        return "copyshoppingcart";
    } else {
                    ...
                    ...
        return "redirect:/home";
    }
}
```

In the JSP I have tried this:

```
<form:errors path="*" cssClass="formError"/>
```

as well as:

```
<form:errors path="fieldName" cssClass="formError"/>
```

Neither works.

Comment: Better show us your JSP code.

Comment: I had to use `@ModelAttribute` to get this working. So the form was preceded by `@ModelAttribute("copyCartForm") @Valid CopyCart copyCartForm, BindingResult result)`
Not sure why though? At other places it works without that.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I had to use `@ModelAttribute` to get this working. So the form was preceded by `@ModelAttribute("copyCartForm") @Valid CopyCart copyCartForm, BindingResult result)`

Comment: This worked for me. It seems that if your model attribute name (copyCartForm) doesn't match the class name of the model (copyCart) that you have to specify it as a parameter to the @ModelAttribute attribute.

Comment: Hey! 

Thanks, I'm looking into this right now and my bindingResult.hasErrors() doesn't seem to be returning anything even though I've added annotations on the model such as notnull etc.

Answer (score 9):

One more approach, If for some reason you cannot use `@ModelAttribute("copyCartForm")` when use follow:

```
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String post(@Valid CopyCart copyCartForm, BindingResult bindingResult, ModelMap modelMap) {
    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        modelMap.put(BindingResult.class.getName() + ".copyCartForm", bindingResult);
        return "copyshoppingcart";
    }
    return "redirect:/home";
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I faced the same issue.

I had to use the `@ModelAttribute("attributeName")` to get the validation error back in response.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure why and I suffered a lot until I figured it out, but you HAVE TO name your bean exactly as your bean class. So copyCartForm should be just copyCart.

```
@RequestMapping(params="action=Confirm Copy", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String copyCart(@Valid CopyCart copyCart, BindingResult result) {
    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        logger.debug("errors in form" + result.toString());
        return "copyshoppingcart";
    } else {
                    ...
                    ...
        return "redirect:/home";
    }
}
```

This must also be changed on the form tag:

```
<form:form action="....." method="..." commandName="copyCart">
```

Answer (score -1):

you need to add this dependency to your pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```