# form:errors does not show a list of errors but form:errors path="x" works

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, hibernate-validator

I'm trying to show a complete list of my form errors.
Now I can do `<form:errors path="x"/>` a few times, but unless I'm mistaken I should be able to just use `<form:errors/>`?
However `<form:errors/>` gives me no output.

Does anyone know why this is happening (and yes, the form:errors is within my form:form)

Comment: It should help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2860756/spring-3-mvc-formerrors-not-showing-the-errors/12515147#12515147

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<form:errors/>` produces errors associated with the command object itself. To get errors for all its fields you need `<form:errors path = "*" />`.