# Spring MVC : form:errors tag

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

How can I check for a particular error on a JSP page and only show it when it is present.

For example I would like to check whether the following error exists using `<c:if>` tag  and only then render it as HTML.

```
<form:errors path="transactionType" cssClass="error"></form:errors>
```

Comment: It should help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2860756/spring-3-mvc-formerrors-not-showing-the-errors/12515147#12515147

Answer (score 6):

Use the `<spring:hasBindErrors name="myFormBean">` tag, and inspect the page-scope errors bean.

[Reference doc link](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/spring-framework-reference/html/apds04.html)

Answer (score 5):

You already get this functionality with the [`<form:errors>`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/view.html#view-jsp-formtaglib-errorstag) tag.  It only renders its contents when there is a corresponding error (based on the `path` attribute), so it is analogous to using a `<c:if>` to first check for an error.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I want to check for the error as I have the input fields inside a table and using < form:errors > tag with the input fields is rendering an unwanted empty space above the input fields when there is no error. I only want the errors to get rendered when they are actually there.